# Left outer join MYSQL returning duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MYSQL Query:

```
select
  sc.supplier,
  sq.query_value,
  sc.cnv_name as name,
  sc.cnv_id,
  sq.query_type_id,
  qt.query_type_desc,
  date_format(sq.query_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as query_date,
  qs.query_status,
  sq.sla_count,
  sq.sla_state,
  sq.assigned_to,
  IfNull(teams.team_count, 0) team_count,
  if(
    sq.sla_state is null
    OR sq.sla_state = '',
    '',
    if(
      sq.sla_state = 0,
      'Query Handler',
      if(
        sq.sla_state = 1,
        'Team Leader',
        if(
          sq.sla_state = 2,
          'Manager',
          if(
            sq.sla_state = 3,
            'Senior Manager',
            'Senior Manager (GSCOP BREACH)'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ) as sla_state_desc,
  if(
    team_count <= 0
    OR team_count is null,
    '',
    if(team_count > 1, '(multiple)', pt.team_desc)
  ) as team
from
  supconversation sc
  left outer join supconvers_querydtls sq on sq.cnv_id = sc.cnv_id
  left outer join querytype qt on qt.query_type_id = sq.query_type_id
  left outer join querystatus qs on qs.query_status_id = sq.query_status_id
  left outer join (
    select
      count(*) team_count,
      tu.user_id
    from
      teamusers tu,
      supconvers_querydtls sq2
    where
      tu.user_id = sq2.assigned_to
  ) teams on (teams.user_id = sq.assigned_to)
  left outer join teamusers tu on tu.user_id = sq.assigned_to
  left outer join portalteam pt on pt.team_id = tu.team_id
where
  sc.supplier = 'SUPTEST1'
  and sc.cnv_type = 'Q'
order by
  query_date desc
```

What I am trying to do is check if a user has a record in `teamusers`. The user can be a part of more than 1 team. This is stored in the `teamusers` table with the columns `team_id, user_id`. If a user has more than 1 record in `teamusers` then return `team` value as `(multiple)`. Otherwise, return the `team_desc` found in the `portalteam` table. The `portalteam` table consists of the columns `team_id,team_desc`.

This query seems to work but it's returning duplicate rows. I imagine this is because there are multiple records for some users in `teamusers`. How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Please post some sample data from teamusers table. And your expected result.

Comment: add a group by and try so to remove the duplicates, sometimes als a DISTINCT helps, but that seems unlikley in your case, but you can try it

Answer (score 0):

If you really get duplicated  rows  then you could try using a select DISTINCT

```
  select distinct
  sc.supplier,
  sq.query_value,
  sc.cnv_name as name,
  sc.cnv_id,
  sq.query_type_id,
  qt.query_type_desc,
  date_format(sq.query_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as query_date,
  qs.query_status,
  sq.sla_count,
  sq.sla_state,
  sq.assigned_to,
  IfNull(teams.team_count, 0) team_count,
  if(
    sq.sla_state is null
    OR sq.sla_state = '',
    '',
    if(
      sq.sla_state = 0,
      'Query Handler',
      if(
        sq.sla_state = 1,
        'Team Leader',
        if(
          sq.sla_state = 2,
          'Manager',
          if(
            sq.sla_state = 3,
            'Senior Manager',
            'Senior Manager (GSCOP BREACH)'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ) as sla_state_desc,
  if(
    team_count <= 0
    OR team_count is null,
    '',
    if(team_count > 1, '(multiple)', pt.team_desc)
  ) as team
from
  supconversation sc
 .....
 .....
```

Comment: doubt that DISTINCT will cut it